# How to detect if a cursor is over a textfield of a button and then move it to the next one?

Tags: java, focus

I need to be able to detect whether or not my mouse is hovering over a a certain button and when I press enter it needs to move to the next button in the grid and cycle all the way around the button grid(the buttons are in their own grid layout).

The program itself is 5000 lines of code, so I din't include it here, if anyone needs it I can send it to you.

[image]

Comment: You should not move the mouse pointer for the user

Comment: I know, but its part of my assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can either make use of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) API or you can add MouseListener along with a [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) somewhat like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextHoverComponent extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    private static final Color DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;

    private static final Color HOVER_TEXT_COLOR = Color.RED;

    private Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);

    private String text = "EXIT";

    private Color textColor = DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR;

    private Point textLocation = new Point(650, 50);

    public TextHoverComponent() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
                checkForHover(event);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
                checkForHover(event);
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
                checkForHover(event);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                checkForHover(event);
            }
        });
    }

    void checkForHover(MouseEvent event) {
        FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(font);

        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        Rectangle textBounds = metrics.getStringBounds(text, g).getBounds();
        g.dispose();

        textBounds.translate(textLocation.x, textLocation.y);

        if (textBounds.contains(event.getPoint())) {
            textColor = HOVER_TEXT_COLOR;
        } else {
            textColor = DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR;
        }
        repaint(textBounds);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(textColor);
        g.drawString(text, textLocation.x, textLocation.y);
    }
}
```

The answer to the other part of the question I don't know that as of now, but I will try to edit this answer and put an answer for that too

**Update:** For moving the mouse position you will need to use the **Robot** class. Here is an example for you:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.awt.Robot;

import java.awt.Toolkit;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;



public class Main 

{



    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException 

    {

        Robot robot = new Robot();



        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();



        robot.mouseMove(0, (int) screenSize.getHeight()-20);



        robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);



    }



}
```